# Replace subtext of a word

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace this string 
 `ramesh@gmail.com`

to

`rxxxxh@gxxxl.com`

this is what I have done so far

`print( re.sub(r'([A-Za-z](.*)[A-Za-z]@)','x', i))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go is to use capturing groups and in the replacement for the parts that should be replaced with `x` return a repetition for number of characters in the matched group.

For the second and the fourth group use a negated character class `[^` matching any char except the listed.

```
\b([A-Za-z])([^@\s]*)([A-Za-z]@[A-Za-z])([^@\s.]*)([A-Za-z])\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HoOHQD/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/fvSYbL)

For example

```
import re

i = "ramesh@gmail.com"

res = re.sub(
    r'\b([A-Za-z])([^@\s]*)([A-Za-z]@[A-Za-z])([^@\s.]*)([A-Za-z])\b',
    lambda x:  x.group(1) + "x" * len(x.group(2)) + x.group(3) + "x" * len(x.group(4)) + x.group(5),
i)
print(res)
```

Output

```
rxxxxh@gxxxl.com
```